# How to create enqueue CLI consumer without symfony or other bundles

Tags: php, redis, message-queue, producer-consumer, enqueue

I have  PHP projects written without any frameworks and I'm using `enqueue/redis` to produce message into redis queue, and I want another project to consume messages. How can I make CLI consumer which will not interrupt after it proceed first message. I know enqueue have CLI commands for symfony, Magento. But I do not see any info how to achieve same without  frameworks.